# Search stops working for "Entire Solution"

Tags: visual-studio

Somehow Visual Studio search has stopped working for me. Anytime I search "Entire Solution" for some text I get this result:

> Find all "[Whatever I was searching for]", Subfolders, Find Results
>   1, "Entire Solution"   No matching text found to look in.   Find was
>   stopped in progress.

Why does it suddenly say "No files were found to look in"?

I've found a number of links on Google that say to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd>, but none of them seem to work for me.

Comment: Issue still present in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Also happens in VS2008. Solution works there too.

Comment: Issue still present in Visual Studio 2013

Comment: It seems Visual Studio's search feature is generally quite buggy  (version 2013 too). I've been working with it extensively in the past months, and apart from its inherent slowness (a turtle compared to Sublime), it often freezes or jams the entire Visual Studio instance. The quite advanced Regex feature is especially buggy, which is even more frustrating considering how awfully useful it is. Couldn't find a decent  solution or perhaps vs extension for this - would be happy to be notified of any. Or will this be improved in version 2015?

Comment: I can still see this issue in VS2015

Comment: Oh, yes - also in VS2017 beta. print screen "solves" the hang for me.

Comment: I can still see this issue in VS2017 Version 15.2 (26430.14) Release.

Comment: My problem turned out to be i had the RegEx box checked and forgot. My search term was improper regex so it never returned results.

Comment: MSVC 2022 have the same issue.

Comment: after almost 15 years and the bug is still there! good work microsoft. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72562941/visual-studio-2022-find-all-in-entire-solution-is-not-working-properly

Answer (score 603, accepted):

I get that problem once in a while. One seemingly nonsensical solution I've found is to click inside the Find Results window (not the Output window). Once the blinking text cursor is visible, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> four or five times. This seems to "unblock" whatever causes the problem.

There are reports <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ScrLk</kbd> may need to be used instead of  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> . If these doesn't work then try <kbd>Break</kbd> alone.

Note from Codeguard: I have found an [explanation and deterministic solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28219093/147805) to this problem

Comment: Voodoo like this should go into the undocumented features section ;-)

Comment: You should also note that closing the studio helps. The problem that occurs is the CLR gets hung up on a process and that is what causes the search to not work. It can range from Intellisense to IIS.

Comment: Before I had found that trick, the only way I could get find-in-files to work again was to reboot the machine. Nothing else worked, not even restarting Visual Studio. Thinking back, I don't know if logging out would've fixed it as well.

Comment: `Ctrl + break` did not work for me.  Instead, `Ctrl + ScrollLock`did work.  This was on VS2010.

Comment: Ctrl+Break worked for me. Is there a way to bring it back to state where it says, "find was stopped in progress."? :)

Comment: I was sceptical. I mean really sceptical. So, I tried it. I was hitting ctrl-creak as many times as I possibly could...and it worked..I mean....it really worked...Holy Crap!

Comment: Poor bugger me. I'm running it on a Macbook. No break or scrolllock key ! I've got to start up the MS on-screen keyboard to do this. Triple DOH !

Comment: The dev team says it's a bug in Windows (that is still not fixed in 8 apparently). Here's a Connect issue on it: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/718217/find-was-stopped-in-progress-while-performing-search-in-visual-studio. Check the comment by iquazee, who did some work to confirm the problem as a non-VS bug.

Comment: Ctrl + break did the trick for me. The issue was present when "Current Project" was selected in my case.

Comment: Worked in visual studio 2008 as well

Comment: It's so magical, I'll never forget this fix. Lol @ Mac users who don't have a Break key :)

Comment: According to that link @ScottBilas posted, they've fixed it for an upcoming release. "Posted by Microsoft on 2/26/2014 at 2:43 PM
We have fixed the submitted bug for an upcoming release of Visual Studio. We do like to hear feedback, so please don’t hesitate to file an issue again.

Thanks!
Language Experience Team"

Comment: Oh damn, first Google result, and this odd fix worked. How peculiar!

Comment: Got the same problem in VS2013 Update 4, restarted visual studio but no luck then i tired all the key combinations and it solved the problem.

Comment: Restarting VS 2010 did not work for me but using the magic CTRL-BREAK combination did the job! Thanks for the trick.

Comment: I got these same symptoms except my problem was related to trying to do replace in files where some of the files had NULL characters. Had to use Notepad++. Worked afterwards in VS2012.

Comment: According to EventViewer, a System.AccessViolationException is being thrown due to an unhandled exception. Stack trace shows that this happens in the method Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsTrackSelectionExPrivate.Register()

Comment: I don't have break button on my keyboard

Comment: ctrl - Break for vs2013 did the job here

Comment: I don't have a scroll lock button on my laptop, do I need to re-buy Visual Studio?

Comment: VS 2015 Update 2 checking in. But hey, we have UWP now!

Comment: @Codeguard I am unsure that editing my answer with a link to yours is kosher.

Comment: I wasn't sure myself, but most people will just read the first answer, curse the magic shaman dances required and live with it. You simply had the advantage of being first and now non-perfect answer vastly outnumbers anything else. Can you agree actually seeing my answer will be helpful?

Comment: Today I got this problem for the first time after working with Visual Studio on a daily basis for about 9 years. It was persistent - for instance, ***restarting*** Visual Studio ***did not help***. But following the instructions in this answer worked!!!! (Ctrl + Break did work.)

Comment: Not only did this not work, it really makes no sense why it would work.  I feel like I just wasted my time doing some meaningless procedure that I already knew wasn't going to work, and it didn't.

Comment: I just had to click into the results pane and it reloaded the solution and worked

Comment: For me: Hit Break, Hit CTRL, release Break, release CTRL.

Comment: Holy, it works. Thanks a ton. I used to restart VM for this. LOL

Comment: I'm experiencing this in VS2017. I've tried all five suggested key combinations (after clicking in the Find Results window). I don't have regular expressions mistakenly checked. I do have include subfolders checked. I've tried different Look In folders, using *.* for the File Type, rebooting, uninstalling extensions, etc.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in 2022.

Comment: Worked for me with Ctrl+ScrollLock in VS 2022. Can't believe this is still an issue!

Comment: Ah, never mind, it still only finds _some_ of the results. Wow, VS is so great. I'm going back to vim.

Comment: Bug still exists in VS 2019. The solution of CTRL + BREAK did not work for me. I tried below steps and it worked
1. Exit VS
2. Change search to 'Current Document' and search once
3. Search back to 'Entire Solution' and search again

Answer (score 88):

Windows 7 Pro SP1 64-bit, Visual Studio 9.0.30729.1

**Didn't Work:**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd>
- Restart of Visual Studio

**Worked:**

- <kbd>Break</kbd> (in Find Result 1 & 2) (only pressed once)

Source: Comments in Gordon's link...

Comment: Same here, I only breaked in "Find Result 1" but that depends on wheteher you use both or just one of the two.

Comment: Thanks ! I had even removed the Scroll Lock key from keyboard and it was not the cause!

Comment: Thanks! Worked for VS 2012 (Update 2)

Comment: In Visual studio 2017 version this "bug" has been fixed! Now search tool remains locked and CTRL+Break doesn't work. Good! :(

Comment: That worked on visual studio 22 community, windows 10

Comment: For me, restarting Visual Studio *did* work on Win 10 with VS2022

Answer (score 62):

**Bug source**

This is neither Visual Studio nor Windows related bug. In fact, the bug is in your keyboard! Many keyboards from different vendors have been reported to be buggy.

**Problem**

If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> and release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> first, then Break gets stuck on a buggy keyboard. If you ever pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> the "wrong" way, you will have this problem with search being interrupted.

**Details**

According to scan code specifications, <kbd>Break</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> are special. They send "make" (press) AND "break" (release) scan codes the moment you press <kbd>Break</kbd>. They send nothing when you release <kbd>Break</kbd>. The buggy keyboard will send the following sequence:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> "make" scan code
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> "make" scan code
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> "break" scan code
4. <kbd>Pause</kbd> "break" scan code

That is, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> is never released, but instead <kbd>Pause</kbd> is released.

**Reproduction**

You could for example use old good Spy++ from Visual Studio tools. Attach it to anything, for example Windows notepad, and monitor messages (I suggest that you select only keyboard messages). Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>, releasing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> first. Check the output from Spy++. You will see the sequence I shown in Details section.

I have tried two different keyboards on the same computer. Logitech K120 has the bug while some other Mitsumi keyboard behaves according to specifications and does not have the bug.

If you think about it, it's easy to understand that correct behavior needs special case handling, while buggy behavior is naive. This is why many different keyboards can be buggy.

**Solution**

Replace your keyboard :)

**Workaround**

You simply need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>, paying attention to releasing <kbd>Break</kbd> first. It doesn't matter which application is active.

Comment: Was highly sceptical of this, but then realised that this problem only happened when I've earlier on in the day had to cancel a batch file.  Just tried doing a ctrl-break but let go of break second and pop, search failed. Repeating letting go of break first and the search magically works. Thanks

Comment: I only can add that it's not necessarily Break key that breaks it all. I've been editing the code a lot with rect. selection copy/paste, and while holding Alt, I've heard the computer beep a lot, very possibly due to releasing mouse button after Alt or something.That way Ctrl key somehow got sticky! All the apps were reacting like it was held. And yes, combinations with Break made it release. So there are several key combos that break the key state, some silly overflow I guess on the Windows side.

Comment: You're right. I get the bug with a "Microsoft wired keyboard 600" too.

Comment: My keyboard is genius and I also have the problem. Your answer is non-sense.

Comment: There are many keyboards that are buggy. Just try what I described, and if it happens, your keyboard is buggy too.

Comment: On a laptop that didn't have a dedicated [pause/break] key I had to do [fn]+[shift] and [fn]+[ctrl]+[shift]

Comment: Disconnect your keyboard and use the virtual one. Same problem. No buggy keyboard.

Comment: That would simply mean that your virtual keyboard is also buggy. Easy to check if you read scan code specifications yourself.

Comment: Actually it seems to be a Windows bug. The work-around worked for me, but with one caveat - I had to use the Ctrl on the other side of the keyboard, that I never use! Also, I use quite expensive keyboard...

Comment: Strange that you call it a keyboard bug! I can search with same keyboard, in Explorer, in Firefox, in IdeaJ, literally in any application without issue, but when I search in Visual studio I don't get anything. Oh, BTW I still have visual studio 2010 in my system and that also can do the search on same project and find results while at same moment visual studio 2019 cannot find anything!

Answer (score 33):

This bug has been in Visual Studio a long time and it never seems to get fixed.

See this MS Connect item from 2004: <strike>http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/105511/find-in-files-says-no-files-were-found-to-look-in-find-was-stopped</strike>

I couldn't believe they still hadn't fixed it in VS2010 - but it's still there :(

The Connect item has been marked as **Closed - Won't Fix**: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/718217/find-was-stopped-in-progress-while-performing-search-in-visual-studio

Comment: Still there in VS2011 beta, too.

Comment: new bug entry is here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/718217/find-was-stopped-in-progress-while-performing-search-in-visual-studio

Comment: Still happening in VS2015.

Comment: Some MS folks are actively engaged with me on Connect in tracking this down. I will post if anything comes out of it, Meanwhile I'm glad to see there may be a workaround with Break/Ctrl-Break. I've been clicking madly on the close (x) button of the Find window until it 'catches', which can take 20 or 30 seconds.

Comment: Still happening in VS2017 and VS2019

Comment: The links in the answer & comments are dead.

Answer (score 20):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ScrLk</kbd> cancel a find operation. Try it. What has happened is that some software layer (presumably Windows) thinks those keys are still being pressed even though they are not. Pressing and releasing them clears the flag.

It could be any of these combinations:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>

<kbd>Break</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ScrLk</kbd>

*Remember that you have multiple control and alt keys on your keyboard* -- try it with each of them. If it's the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key + <kbd>ScrLk</kbd>, pressing the left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is not going to resolve the issue.

[Here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/718217/find-was-stopped-in-progress-while-performing-search-in-visual-studio) is the Connect issue which Microsoft closed as "Won't Fix".

If this is a recurring problem for you, there is [a Visual Studio extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/23d270a7-c74c-47e4-ba14-d9341e9017ff) that suppresses the virtual key that causes the problem.

Comment: Nothing worked for me, except for that VS extension you linked. Thank you!

Comment: The visual extension link did not work for me in VS 2012

Answer (score 15):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> have stopped working on Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.

My friend told me going to:

1. **Tools → Import and Export Settings:**
   [image]
2. **Choose: Reset all settings → Next**
   [image]
3. **Choose: No, just reset settings, overwriting my current settings → Next**
   [image]
4. **Choose: General → Finish**
   [image]

Comment: Looked around on web for an hour finally this one fixed it. I was bout to re-install, this saved me time. Thank you

Answer (score 13):

In my case I had a bogus character in the "Look at these file types:" field in the search window.

Removing the character solved the problem.

Visual Studio 2017

[image]

Answer (score 12):

I was using Visual Studio 2022 (tried with both professional and community, V 17.2.5), my search function was not working in `Find in All Files`, so I browsed to my solution folder, under `.vs\{ProjectName}` folder, there is another folder with name `FileContentIndex`. After closing visual studio and deleting this folder, and restarting vs, seemed to solve my problems, and my `Find in All Files` started functioning correctly.

Comment: This worked for me. I'm able to find the correct strings/files again.

Answer (score 10):

I tried all the previous options. They didn't work for me, but reading them made me sure that this is a bug, and I will have to try some unknown ways to get it working. So, I tried a *simple file search* in Visual Studio 2010 in:

1. The current document
2. All the open documents

Both of which worked.

Then I tried *Find in Files* and woah! It started working.

Answer (score 10):

Search solution in Visual Studio 2012 is broke. I tested this on three machines, did not work on two. What I found which does work is click on drop down arrow next to search field and select Find all. This is a bit of pain because you have to select drop down every time you search in solution.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately none of these special key strokes work for me. Only restarting Visual Studio 2010 seems to work for me.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem in Visual Studio 2013 (Update 3). None of the key combinations listed previously worked for me. I had `*.cs` selected in the FileTypes.

To get it working, I changed it to `*.*`, and then back again to `*.cs` - now it works.

Answer (score 4):

I have been using Visual Studio 13 without this problem for couple of years now and I started having this issue after applying Update 5 or it could be a weird keys combo pressed by me unknowingly which triggered it, I don't know for sure.

Echelon_Force's solution worked for me. Thanks!

**Didn't Work:**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd>

**Worked:**

<kbd>Break</kbd> (in Find Result 1 & 2 window - Only pressed once)

Happy finding in files!

Answer (score 3):

All of the combinations of <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> and <kbd>Break</kbd> didn't do anything for me.  As a workaround, I added the solution directory to the Search Folders (the second ellipsis button), then changed the Look In field to the solution directory.  The root problem still exists, but for me, this is functionally the same thing.

(Visual Studio 2013, Windows 8.1, x64)

[image: screenshotomwhat]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as glenneroo today, after updating Visual Studio 2019 to 16.4.3. Found a solution that worked for me [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/683843/find-and-replace-window-not-working-in-2019-latest.html).

Open `Find Options` and check if there is a (special) character in the `Look at these file types` text field. If so, remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I am running Visual Studio 2012 Professional in a Virtual Machine, connecting using rdesktop from a Linux machine.

None of the other suggestions worked, but solved the problem was:

- Go to the 'Find and Replace' screen. (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> in my case)
- Enter a search text and choose 'Entire Solution'
- Hit 'Find Next', it should find a result.
- Hit 'Find All', now works without aborting. (Note, i hit my Mouse really hard and some swearing was involved, too, but I don't think that has any relevance apart from a psychological one :D )

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2013 after Update 3, I had the same problem. Before, I could just put ".cs" or ".cshtml" in the **Look at these file types:** and it would work. But after Update 3 I now have to put "*.cs" or "*.cshtml" (or whatever file types I want to search in) and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It only seems to lock-up if I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (*Find in Entire Solution*) and never if I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (*Find in Files*).

Answer (score 1):

This works for me after everything else didn't or worked only sometimes:

Do the search, and while searching, **hold** <kbd>CRTL</kbd> all the time and keep pressing <kbd>Break</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching for multiple file types, they must be separated with a ; character, not a space.

This returns the correct results:

> *.cs;*.vb;*.js;*.aspx

This returns nothing at all:

> *.cs *.vb *.js *.aspx

This isn't the problem the original poster, but for other people who can't figure out why their search isn't working, this could be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Another late-to-the-party answer, but I found yet another "solution" for this problem.

When it looks as if the Visual Studio app has frozen on search...leave it alone. Don't close it. Don't restart it. Just let it go for about 10-15 minutes and the problem may correct itself, as it did in my specific case. I'm not sure as to why leaving it alone solved the problem, although my **wholly uneducated guess** is that Visual Studio is building some sort of an index to be able to search files and running into a snag. Once the 10-15 minutes are up and VS completes its search, it seems fine after that.

Answer (score 1):

Probably won't apply to most situations, but what fixed it for me was turning off 'Use Regular Expressions' in the search window. I had previously been using Regular Expressions for some tricky replacements and didn't turn off when finished. I think perhaps it was interpreting part of simple replace text (see below - had some special characters) as the start of an incomplete or malformed regular expression, and so couldn't actually do any matching. Would be nice if it told you!

[image: Disable use regular expressions]

Comment: You're right, it should have told you. However, the example above shows a `(` character without a match in the "Find what" text. The "Replace with" text is fine, since parenthesis are not special in that box.

Comment: Oddly enough I had to do the opposite in VS 2022.

Answer (score 1):

That `Ctrl`+`Break` trick worked for me for years, it's really interesting to finally understand [why this happens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28219093/468725). With VS2015 I have somewhat related problem with search: my `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`F` simply does not work, this key combination seems to be ignored when I press it. I tried to reinstall even VS 2015 and I still got that same broken behavior.

In case somebody has identical problem, here's what was the reason:

I turns out that for whatever random reason VS2015 shows that "find in files" dialog on another monitor that's attached to my PC. That other monitor is 4K Samsung TV that normally stays "Off" and I have no clue why VS 2015 sends that search dialog box to that monitor. Surprisingly, when I turn on my TV the search dialog moves to the primary monitor on its own!

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd> works for Visual Studio 2008

Comment: This happens a lot. And it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing worked for me. I use also Resharper. So I had to reset my VS key bindings and reapply Resharper shortcuts. Only this got me it working.

1. Reset current keyboard configuration (Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard | Reset).
2. Go to ReSharper | Options | Environment | Keyboard & Menus | "Visual Studio"  | Apply Scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Tried all the solution, but the fixed of mine was I accidently change to another language keyboard on my windows, after I change back to English keyboard, it work, finally I can `ctrl + shirt + f`

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using VS2019 16.7.7, and, if I try to find something in the whole solution, VS never finds all the occurrences, sometimes only one, or none.

In some recent release of VS2019 (perhaps 16.5 or 16.6) the old "Find and replace" dialog was replaced by a new "Find in files" dialog, and this new one is failing for me. One solution that worked for me was to disable the new "Find in files" and keep using the old "Find and replace" dialog by checking `Use previous Find In Files` in `Tools > Options > Environment > Preview features`.

However, I observed that this was only failing in one of my open Visual Studio instances, so I tried the simple "close VS and open it again", enabled the new "Find in files" functionality, and it started working.

Two possible solutions, in case the simple "close and open again" fails.

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Preview Version 17.8.0 Preview 3.0 -- Searching the Entire Solution fails to work all the time now. I usually resort to starting VSCode in the folder I want to search and use that.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me. Visual Studio → menu *Windows* → *Reset Window Panel*. The resizing of Visual Studio made it to hide the option.

Comment: In some versions of Visual Studio it is called "Reset Window Layout", not "Reset Window Panel".

Answer (score 0):

This was one of my biggest problems with Visual Studio. For me (Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015) the find in all files window got locked with a white-out, and guess what, hitting <kbd>print screen</kbd> solves it.

Answer (score 0):

This has begun occurring for me with the update to Version 15.8.8 of Visual Studio.  None of the above steps worked.  There is no error.  Just what appears to be a 'stuck' search.

I had recently installed ApexSQL Refactor 2018.03.0331.  Uninstalling this did not resolve the issue and does not seems to be the cause.  It seems to be related to Version 15.8.8 of Visual Studio update.

I completely uninstalled Visual Studio and reinstalled Version 15.8.8 again.  The issue with Ctrl-Shift-F searching the Entire Solution is no longer an issue.  Whatever caused the problem *does* resolve after uninstalling and installing.

I once again installed ApexSQL Refactor 2018.03.0331 and everything still works well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar situation with Visual Studio Community 2017 and now 2019 (patched up to 16.1.4). In my case it doesn't show any results, it just searches forever without ever finding anything. My solution was to undock the "Find and Replace" dialog and move it to anywhere in a floating position. After undocking it seems to work fine, even after docking it again back to it's original position.