# Find in Visual Studio does nothing

Tags: visual-studio, replace, find

I tried a series of possible solutions (/ResetSettings, control scrolllock, control-pausebreak, pausebreak in the find panel, scrolllock in the find panel, and all sometimes all at once) to no avail. When I click find absolutely nothing happens.

Find-all and replace/replace-all respond the same way. I'm on the verge of a reinstall, but I've read that will not solve the problem. What is going on and what can I do? Anyone experience this?

Comment: what's your context? Selection? Entire Solution?, Current Project?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work 100% of the time, no project loaded, entire solution, current project, and in directory. I have been using the search all directory feature more than quite a bit, and I feel it is the root of the cause. The button is active, clicking it does nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate here [Visual Studio search stops working for “Entire Solution”][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892126/visual-studio-search-stops-working-for-entire-solution

Answer (score 0):

I caved in and reinstalled Visual Studio. It works now.

Comment: I suppose if that worked for you then you might as well accept it as the anwer.