# "Find all" in Visual Studio 2010 is not working as expected

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a problem with Visual Studio 2010 when I try to find all some phrase word.

[image]

You can see, I tried to find "header-logo", but Visual Studio couldn't find it having "header-logo" beside the finding box (aspx file), but Visual Studio doesn't display it.

The same with other type files. It just shows the matched phrase in the CSS file.

[image]

What is the reason?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are asking. You used the "Find All" feature to find "header-logo", and it matched the phrase in a CSS file. Isn't that what it is *supposed* to do? What else were you expecting?

Comment: Thank for your feedback, I've edited the question

Comment: The edit didn't help much, I still don't understand the problem. You do know that when you use the "Find In Files" feature, and tell it to look in the "Entire Solution," it doesn't highlight the matches in the current file, right? If you double-click on the result in the "Find Results" toolbox window, it will take you to the match. If you want an incremental search that highlights matches, use Ctrl+F (instead of Ctrl+Shift+F).

Comment: Cody Gray, you can see, I was searching "header-logo". And the phrase "header-logo" is in 2 files (HeaderFrame.css and Header.aspx). But VS2010 just show the matched phrase in HeaderFrame.css, Header.aspx is not. As the same when I found another phrase, VS2010 just find in css file, not another file type.
I think now you understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Search stops working for "Entire Solution"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892126/search-stops-working-for-entire-solution)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Find was stopped in progress"

*[Visual Studio "Find in Files" does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207954/visual-studio-find-in-files-does-not-work)*

I solve it by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd>, but you have to do it just right: hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, press <kbd>Break</kbd>, release <kbd>Break</kbd>, and release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

You can also reboot. I know it seemed unlikely to help in this case, but before the problem and solution were as well understood, there were a lot of people rebooting to solve it...

Comment: oh my god, thank you so much. I can't imagine about it. Still don't understand, maybe it's black magic as a person commented in your link that you sent to me