# "Find in files" in Visual Studio 2017 does not work

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, findinfiles

When I use the "find in files" Window in Visual Studio 2017 and select "entire solution" to search in, the search does not work: the result window opens and the options for the search are listed, but nothing else happens or is listed in the result window.

When I select "all opened files" or "current window" instead of "entire solution", search works without problems.

It does not depend on the solution opened: I tried to search in several different solutions and also in a completely new one.

I already tried the suggestions here: [Visual Studio "Find in Files" does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207954/visual-studio-find-in-files-does-not-work) but nothing worked. Maybe there is something else to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I re-installed Visual Studio 2017 and that solved the problem.

Comment: Maybe your computer was hacked.