# Visual Studio "Find in Files" unable to find matches in solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, findinfiles

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.5.0.

When I use `ctrl + shift + f` and try to search for a common string in my solution, the search results keep coming up empty (even with match case and match whole word off):

[image]

But if I search in "All Open Documents" then the results are correct. This has been happening across several solutions. I saw [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55278081/find-in-files-in-visual-studio-2017-does-not-work) having a similar issue, but I don't want to resort to the hours of reinstalling VS.

Comment: Does it match if you disable `Match whole word`?  It seems like a solution-wide _symbol_ search would be better since a (properly-functioning) search for `[Fact()]` won't match `[Fact]` on the previous member in your screenshot, despite them being equivalent.

Comment: If I don't match by word or case still nothing comes up - I'll be sure to clarify that in my question

Comment: Are you able to update beyond 16.5.0?  Some of the updates in that series, particularly [16.5.4](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-v16.5#--visual-studio-2019-version-1654), contain fixes to the find experience, although no mention of this issue specifically.  Does [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/985099/find-stopped-finding-1.html) sound like the same problem?

Comment: That looks like exactly the same issue, and one of their comments seem to have temporarily "fixed" the problem :) clicking and unclicking the "keep modified files open after Replace All" seems to have unstuck the search,  but time will tell  for how long.