# Visual Studio 2010 Professional Find and Replace Not Working

Tags: visual-studio-2010

My find and replace has stopped working.

Background: 
I have a paid version Visual Studio 2010 installed. I also was running a trial version of Ultimate. However, the trial expired so I un-installed Ultimate. After the un-install of Ultimate, I can no longer do a global search in VS Professional.

Anyone have any ideas? Where should Microsoft.VisualStudio.Progression.GraphModel reside and why is it causing my search to fail? I tried running a repair on VS Professional without luck.

Error Message:
In the find results, I get the following:

Find all "test", Subfolders, Find Results 1, "Current Project"
The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.

1) Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Progression.GraphModel, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Resulting in: An exception occurred while trying to create an instance of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Fragments.LanguageContext'.

Resulting in: Cannot activate part 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Fragments.LanguageContext'.
Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Fragments.LanguageContext -->  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Fragments.LanguageContext

Resulting in: Cannot get export 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Fragments.LanguageContext (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Fragments.ILanguageContext")' from part 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Fragments.LanguageContext'.
Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Fragments.LanguageContext (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Fragments.ILanguageContext") -->  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Fragments.LanguageContext

Resulting in: Cannot set import 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Fragments.EventsManager..ctor (Parameter="languageContext", ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Fragments.ILanguageContext")' on part 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Fragments.EventsManager'.
Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Fragments.EventsManager..ctor (Parameter="languageContext", ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Fragments.ILanguageContext") -->  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Fragments.EventsManager

Resulting in: Cannot get export 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Fragments.EventsManager (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Fragments.IEventsManager")' from part 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Fragments.EventsManager'.
Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Fragments.EventsManager (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Fragments.IEventsManager") -->  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Fragments.EventsManager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out what was wrong. The reason I switched to Ultimate to begin with was to use this plugin called [Code Bubbles](http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/06/debugger-canvas) (which required Ultimate). When I switched back to Professional after my trial expired, the plugin got into a strange state that was causing other parts of Visual Studio to fail. Once I fully uninstalled the plugin, search returned to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Strange. Have you tried using ctrl + break? As suggested here:

[Search stops working for "Entire Solution"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892126/visual-studio-search-stops-working)

> ... you should click inside the Find Results window, not the Output window. Once the 
>   blinking text cursor is visible, hit ctrl-break four or five times. That should do the 
>   trick.
>   - DJ Couchy Couch