# Visual Studio 2017 Pro - Find Next takes multiple seconds

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When I press "find next" when searching a reasonably large project it takes 3-4 seconds even if the next instance is literally 3 characters away. If I change from "entire solution" to "project" it is instant, despite the entire solution being approximately the same size as the project.

Pressing "find all" finds all results in under a second.

Is there a cache or something I can clear to fix this issue?

I am using resharper however disabling it makes no change.

edit:

Ok I fixed it by going Tools -> Import Export Settings and performing a "reset all"

Very annoying as now I have to set everything up again. If I revert to my backed up settings it becomes slow again. Who can I submit this to to see if it is a bug?

[Search stops working for "Entire Solution"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892126/search-stops-working-for-entire-solution)

Edit2: problem is back and fix no longer works.

Comment: Post your fix as an answer :)

Comment: You can report bugs over at [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/directory/)

Comment: I will post as an answer just wanted to get some advice how to report a bug first. Thanks

Comment: "You are not authorized to submit the feedback for this connection." when I go to that link it won't let me submit a bug. I'm logged into my MS account. Ideas?

Comment: Ok the settings file did not fix it. Problem came back immediately after and deleting it does not fix it now.