# Visual Studio 2022 Find All in Entire Solution is not working properly

Tags: search, visual-studio-2022

I've just started to use Visual Studio 2022 and I'm trying to search something via ctrl+F and 'Find All' function but it is not finding the key that I'm searching for, even though I know there is such a key in a file in one of my projects in the solution. Do I miss a configuration step after a clean installation?

Note: I am able to find the key when I search in 'Current Document'

Comment: I've found that whenever I try to search across an entire solution, I often have to press enter on my keyboard twice for it to attempt to find something.  The first enter press gets ignored.  It has always been this way for me.

Comment: @TimothyG. I haven't come across with such a problem, enter key works fine in my case. Furthermore, I've always been using 'Find All' button rather than using the enter key itself.

Comment: In version 17.4.5, it still does not listing anything via "find all". 

The only workaround that solves it for me,  is checking “use regular expressions” that seems to work...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Visual Studio currently has a bug that is fixed and pending release.

I assume that you are using Turkish region format settings, based on your username. This bug affects users with Turkish regional settings. Probably you have been experiencing the same problem.

Source: [Find in entire solution (Ctrl + Shift + F) cannot match queries containing lowercase 'i' with Turkish region format settings](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Find-in-entire-solution-does-not-working/10047177)

**Edit:**
The fix has been released.

Comment: Thanks a lot, after I had checked the link you've provided, I realized that my issue is caused by what you have mentioned above. 
I saw a workaround comment in the link you've shared as following;
'Opening the start menu, typing in ‘Region’ and selecting ‘Region Control Panel’, and changing your Windows UI ‘Format’ settings from ‘Turkish’ to another locale.'
I've done this workaround and now I don't have any problems at all with searching, this will work until the pending release is completed.

Comment: I'm not using Turkish still getting caching issues where the same search term won't always work

Comment: @msteel9999 It's probably because of another bug or something. Because I had no issues since the fix is released.

Comment: How long is it going to be "pending"? And it has nothing to do with the Turkish language. It's broken af.

Comment: It's not pending. The fix is released a long time ago and it fixed my problem. If you have a similar problem, then it's a newer bug.

Comment: Still broken in VS 17.7.5, for me, the fix apparently fixed nothing (English user here). Also, sadly the workarounds mentioned everywhere do not work. Adding a random word, saving and looking for that word does not make the search work. Also disabling _Use indexing with find in files_ in Tools -> Options as suggested by the developer community does not work, not even after restarting VS.

Answer (score 27):

Thanks guys

Changed the "Look in" setting to the root folder path of my solution instead of selecting the "Entire Solution" option. (Use the three dots button.) This returned the results i was expecting.
This worked!!!

Comment: After 7 years of SO silence, I'm so glad you shared this answer @krutika - it worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me!  Thank you.  I've been using grepWin but can finally search again just using VS.

Comment: This is for `Find in Files` command, not `Quick Find` or `Quick Replace` that we get by pressing Ctrl+F or Ctrl+H shortcut! in quick find/replace window there is no such three dots button.

Answer (score 21):

To fix search: Close visual studio, then delete the hidden `.vs` folder in the folder where your solution file lives

the .vs folder can safely be deleted. It will automatically be created again as soon as you open your visual studio solution again.

This is my general fix for most issues in Visual studio, and it often solves my problems.

Comment: Closed VS then deleted every folder in %TEMP% that started with VS. Re-opened VS and tried the search again.

This did NOT solve the issue for me.

Comment: @Bucket the .vs folder that I am referring to is the hidden folder named .vs in the directory where your visual studio solution is, not in the %TEMP% directory. In the temp directory I deleted everything that could be deleted, regardless of the name

Comment: I had this same issue in latest version of Visual Studio 2022 (English/US).  Closing visual studio and deleting the .vs folder did the trick

Comment: Same here, so I've removed references to the %TEMP% folder from the answer

Comment: If you delete the .vs folder, you will lose some other temporary settings, like what files you have open in the editor.

Comment: Before deleting the .vs folder, you can try just closing and reopening Visual Studio.  This worked for me: after reopening, Find in Files on the entire solution worked.

Answer (score 14):

There seems to be a bug in the caching mechanism. I find I have to use all sorts of stupid tricks to force it to clear its cache and run the search properly, e.g. adding a nonsense word to one of my files, running the find in files for that word (which will succeed), removing it and then running my original query again (which will now succeed). It's very annoying.

Comment: I had this same nonsense bug and this worked for me on Visual Studio 2022. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently they have fixed it in the latest version. (Unconfirmed.)

Comment: fingers crossed...

Comment: Still broken...

Comment: I just updated to 17.3.5 because of this issue and it did not fix it.  This, however, did. 
 Thanks!

Comment: This is quite scary bug, I encountered it today on VS 2022 17.3.5, the last time I had it was on some previous VS versions. It might cause committing something broken. Honestly don't understand how this is not fixed...

Comment: Still broken in VS 17.3.6. (Using English GB language not Turkish)
Was only finding *some* results. It missed a result that was literally on the screen in front of me, in a file that was part of the solution.

Comment: Still broken in VS 2022 17.4.1 . This trick helped me, thanks!

Comment: I reported the issue on developercommunity.visualstudio.com, please upvote it here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-2022-Find-And-Replace---Fi/10213540?

Comment: @xhafan, super idea, but I'm getting "Unexpected error. Sorry, we couldn't send your vote. Please retry now or sign out, sign in, and try again" - probably they don't want it to be upvoted anymore.

Comment: Still broken in 17.5.0   The fix above still works, however. The voting on the developercommunity site is still broken too. Yay Microsoft 

Comment: still broken 17.5.5

Comment: Still broken in 17.6.4, I'm sure it worked in some previous version.

Comment: Still broken in 17.6.5, and voting on developercommunity is also still broken - but at least the issue now it has a tag that says "Fixed - Pending release"

Comment: Still broken in VS 17.7.5, and the workarounds do not work (adding a random word, saving and looking for that word; disabling _Use indexing with find in files_ in Tools -> Options; restarting VS). **The only solution for me was to use the _Find and Replace_ feature (CTRL+Shift+H) and manually select the solution directory as per [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74374383/3873799).** The normal search (CTRL+F) remains broken.

Comment: Still broken in 17.8.6

Answer (score 9):

VS2022 v17.4.3

I was having a similar issue and tracked it down to the selected file types in the **Find in Files** tab. It was originally set to file types that I don't work with, e.g. `*.c`, `*.cpp`. Once I set the File Types to the ones I do work with - e.g. `*.cs`, `*.cshtml` - the find worked as expected.
[image: Find in Files - File Types]

Comment: the simplest solution...  IDK why this setting was different than I usually took. Thanks.

Comment: Does not work for me. VS 17.7.5. This [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74374383/3873799) worked.

Comment: Silly workaround but this is the only one that worked for me, after trying virtually all other solutions presented here. The released fix https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-2022-Find-And-Replace---Fi/10213540 does not fix the issue for me.

Comment: This worked for me on VS 17.7.6

Comment: I think there is still a bug (I have 17.8.3) when those types are being set with no clear trigger instead of the default `*` (search in all file types in solution). I kept getting those file types when doing find...replace in solution and solved by reverting to `*`.

Answer (score 2):

In the "*Find in Files*" tab of the "*Find and Replace*" window i did the following:

**Changed the "*Look in*" setting to the root folder path of my solution** instead of selecting the "*Entire Solution*" option. (Use the three dots button.) This returned the results i was expecting.

If your solution setup is particularly complicated you can search multiple folder paths at once using a semi colon as a separator.

That search seems to take a moment to return every time I search that way. So I'm *guessing* this kind of search does not cache it's results in VS.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the @JoeHernandez answer of "ensure the correct File Types option is selected" - it is possible to inadvertently change this setting (as I did) if you happen to be moving the mouse wheel while the cursor is passing over the File Type options drop down even if that control doesn't have focus.

Also be advised that deleting the .vs hidden folder deletes the open files tracking mechanism - I have over 60 carefully organized open files at present.  Thankfully I was able to restore the .vs folder from the previous day's backup and (after selecting the correct File Type option) SHIFT+CTL+F/SHIFT+CTRL+H are functioning properly again.

Answer (score 0):

And, I still have this issue with the latest Visual Studio 2022 (17.4.2). For me, it seems to be related to using the "Show All Files" view for each of the projects in the Solution. If I disable that for all of the projects, Find in Files seems to work as expected. It continues to work for some time if I switch back to "Show All Files" view, until it doesn't.

I have all of my projects setup using "Show All Files" though, so my overall experience is that at least once a day "Find In Files" just stops working.

Comment: i have same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that if you close all code tabs then hit Ctrl+F a 'different' find window pops up and it does work when finding across the entire solution.

(Although I'm still using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, but the issue might still be the same).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same problem on a cloned project from GitHub.  One of the folder names had a period in the name: ".NET Framework".  I renamed the folder to remove the period and it fixed the problem.

`https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples`

To recreate the problem:
Search for "applicationSecret" within the "..\Projects\GitHub\PowerBI-Developer-Samples\.NET Framework\Embed for your customers\AppOwnsData.sln" solution.