# Visual Studio 2022 Find in Files not working at all

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72562941/visual-studio-2022-find-all-in-entire-solution-is-not-working-properly), my Find in Files is not working at all.  I type in my query, click Find All, and the window goes away, does not open the Find results window.

I tried re-launching Visual Studio, and it is currently running in Admin mode.

I also tried installing pending Windows Updates, and rebooting.

Does anyone know how to fix this?  It has been working for months, suddenly stopped working today.

Version is:  2022, 17.5.0

Comment: Wrong version number, use Help > About.  But sure, VS2022 got very buggy at version 17.4.0 and Find in Files got plenty of problems.  [Example](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS2022-Find-in-Files-sometimes-does-not/10264806).  Check if the workarounds help, do consider downgrading to an older more stable release.

Comment: Oops, was looking at .NET version, thanks.  Downgrading is not an option, got way too much code in C# 9 - over a year's worth.  I find it funny they ask us to update to a preview release of a buggy software, and try to rely on writing production code in that.  I tried all the steps, waited for background tasks to finish. Removing .vs folder finally worked.  Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, VS2019 is currently very stable and supports C# v9.

Comment: Oh, I thought 9 was only on 22.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed [these steps](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS2022-Find-in-Files-sometimes-does-not/10264806), what finally worked was removing the .vs folder for the solution and relaunching VS, let background tasks finish (indexing took a long time).

Thanks Hans Passant!

Comment: Those steps worked for me as well! Thank you 