# Search results missing in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio

In the file Foo.razor, I have the code `<span style="font-size: smaller">`. When I search for "font-size: sm" in the entire solution, there are 3 results, 1 of course in Foo.razor. But when I add an "a", so I search for "font-size: sma", I only get 2 results. Visual Studio does not find it in Foo.razor. Why and how can I get really all results?
Adding more letters does not help. With less letters, the text is found in Foo.razor. But I do not think, it is the number of letters, because searching for "font-size: sma" does deliver results, but not the one in Foo.razor.

I know, there is an issue with the search results, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892126/search-stops-working-for-entire-solution). But the accepted answer does not solve my problem.

Here's a screenshot of my search window:
[image: screenshot of search window]

Many thanks!