# Visual Studio 2008 stopped processing "find all"

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Suddenly, Visual Studio 2008 doesn't execute "find all" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>) for the solution correctly. This happened two days ago in the office and now on the computer at home.

I'm looking for a method, which is definitely declared in code, but Visual Studio 2008 outputs in Find Results window:

```
Find all "wlOutFile", Subfolders, Find Results 2, "Entire Solution", "*.*"
  No files were found to look in.
  Find was stopped in progress.
```

The options looks like this:

[image]

Comment: @Nico YES! Yhank you! "Ctrl + ScrLk". helped. I'll delete the question

Comment: This is a common bug unfortunatly. Hopefully your question will help others find a result!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem in Visual Studio 2008, and unfortunately (from what I know) it has not been resolved. Check this other Stack Overflow question: *[Visual Studio "Find" results in "No files were found to look in. Find stopped progress."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259398/visual-studio-find-results-in-no-files-were-found-to-look-in-find-stopped-pr)*