# Go To Definition: "Cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret."

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I suddenly started experiencing a problem today in my project where clicking Go To Definition gives me a strange error: "Cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret."

[image]

I first noticed it some time after installing [Costura.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Costura) via NuGet. I've since uninstalled it but the problem persists. I've cleaned and rebuilt the solution multiple times. There are no instances of "Fody" or "Costura" anywhere in my git commit history, before or after the point in time when this started happening, so I'm thinking that one of my .gitignore'd files is stuck in a bad state.

The problem only occurs if the definition being targeted is in another file; Go To Definition for something in the currently opened file works fine. Peek Definition works fine too. Other solutions/projects work fine as well -- it's only this one that's causing issues.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015. The issue doesn't seem to occur in the 2013 version.

Why does this error occur and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try to clear the Temp files related to VS 2015 and try it

Comment: Same problem. **Peek works, Go To does not.** I can use peek and **promote** for two-click solution. WTF. Cache clearing does not help. I even reopened the solution from C: (as I have mapping B: = C:\devel), cleared and rebuilded solution, restarted VS and even PC... nothing helps.

Comment: Hitting refresh icon in solution explorer while focused on the project solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The last couple of days I've been getting this error, at least twice a day.. really annoying!
None of the solutions proposed here has worked for me. What I found, and since it was pretty difficult to find I'm writing it down here, was to:

- Close Visual
- Open Console and navigate to Visual installation folder, in my computer is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE
- run devenv.exe /resetuserdata
- Open Visual Studio, it's going to take some time to load.

Disclaimer:
I'm using Xamarin

**TAKE INTO CONSIDERATION WHAT @OzSolomon and @xCasper HAVE SAID:**

@OzSolomon

> ## Know that this will reset many of your IDE customization, including
>   installed plugins.
>
>  Make sure you're comfortable with that before using
>   /resetuserdata

@xCasper

> If you have your settings synced through Microsoft, however, most of
>   the preferences seem to restore themselves. I say most because it
>   seems my keybindings did not restore and are back to being default.
>   Everything else, such as my selected theme and colorization choices,
>   the layout of my IDE (where I have tabs for instance), and what not
>   seem to of come back.

Comment: This is ultimately the solution that worked for me so I'll accept this one; however, as other users have mentioned in other answers, there may indeed be multiple solutions to the problem.

Comment: To anyone considering this: Know that this will reset many of your IDE customization, including installed plugins.  Make sure you're comfortable with that before using `/resetuserdata`

Comment: This definitely fixed the issue for me. Please note what @OzSolomon said about it wiping your data. If you have your settings synced through Microsoft, however, most of the preferences seem to restore themselves. I say most because it seems my keybindings did not restore and are back to being default. Everything else, such as my selected theme and colorization choices, the layout of my IDE (where I have tabs for instance), and what not seem to of come back.

Comment: This "Know that this will reset many of your IDE customization, including installed plugins. Make sure you're comfortable with that before using /resetuserdata" should go in bold with "WARNING" title. -1

Comment: @VarvaraKalinina I assumed that "Take into consideration..." in bold and all capitals was going to be enough. My bad, gonna change it.

Comment: @fabricio I know that you did not mean anything bad, but as many people I don't always finish reading the whole answer on SO. If I saw some kind of ATTENTION in the beginning of your answer I would not need to spend last two hours restoring my VS extensions and syntax coloring. This is mostly my fault, though, I was just too angry and downvoted your answer even though it does work.

Comment: I almost did that "reset" thing in my VS17, but after reading the comment about it here, I decided to wait with that. My question is - if I save the current settings of my VS, run it with the "reset" option and then import back the settings, will I get VS back with everything I had, but with the "fix" of the reset option, or will the import bring back the issue with it??...

Comment: I haven’t tried that. My guess would be that the fix won’t appear again after resetting and importing settings.. but that’s only what I think

Comment: Before trying this and resetting user data, try "clean solution" option mentioned below.

Comment: On VS2017 (15.8.1) I tried all the solutions provided for this question. At last, only this solution worked.

Comment: @AshishSingh same happened to me but 2 years ago, it’s incredible we are still facing same issue.

Comment: for those who still have this problem, maybe this helps:

follow this steps:


"
1) Right click on "References" in the Solution Explorer
2) Select "Manage NuGet Packages"
3) Under the "Installed" tab search fro "Microsoft.Net.Compilers"
4) Select "Microsoft.Net.Compilers"
5) On the side window of "Microsoft.Net.Compilers" click the update button

That should allow you navigate to definitions",

you can see the original post here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/505489/cannot-navigate-to-the-symbol-under-the-caret-3.html

Comment: As per Anthony's comment below (now the highest rated answer) "closed Visual Studio, deleted ".vs" folder (in the solution folder) then reopened Visual Studio"

Comment: Just Cleaning the solution and then Building the solution worked for me.

Answer (score 168):

I got the same problem. I did all those steps mentioned in all above comments. It didn't work. But when I closed Visual Studio, deleted ".vs" folder (in the solution folder) then reopened Visual Studio. It now works like a charm. The problem is gone.

Comment: This worked when cleaning the solution and emptying the symbol cache did not work. It does delete your solution startup settings.

Comment: This seems to be caused by upgrading from Visual Studio 15.4 to 15.5.

Comment: So I deleted the .vs folder and re-opened VS then did a "Rebuild Solution". That seems to solve the problem for me.

Comment: I tried many 'fixes' to no avail. This one worked, thank you for the post!

Comment: Just deleted the unnamed file in .vs folder

Comment: I also tried a lot of other things before this! But only deleting this .vs folder I did get rid of this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me on VS17 Enterprise, although rebuilding took around 30 mins. Worth it.

Comment: Its saviour for me.. thnx alot

Comment: Thank you. Simplest Solution.

Comment: This is way safer and much less troublesome than the accepted answer, +1

Comment: this worked for me. @Jeff E,  in my opinion this should be marked as a correct answer

Comment: Yeee, you are my saver:)) Tnx

Comment: Arg, this is not working. I deleted the .vs folder in my project and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Had this problem with VS & a Unity project. Ended up deleting two .vs folders, closing both VS & Unity, then starting Unity and then VS and that fixed it (cause there was no clean option for me in VS, I assume cause the building etc is done in Unity).

Answer (score 62):

I tried David's solution (the one about clicking Empty Symbol Cache option) but it didn't work for me.

How did I solve it?

- Close all files
- Clean solution
- Rebuild solution

For me this error does not make sense but I solved doing this!

Comment: Worked for me too on Visual Studio 2015. I was using ReSharper command where i came across this error.

Comment: Worked for me too in VS 2017. The problem was I was using old files presumably files that I was using when I'd attached to a process.

Comment: Worked fine with VS2015

Comment: Thanks. This solution worked for me. Using VS Community 2017

Comment: Awesome! Works for me on Visual Studio 2019. I totally forgot to clean and build. Thanks

Comment: It works for me on VS 2015 pro, in the end it's due to one package missing issue.

Comment: This worked for me on a new laptop, freshly installed VS and downloaded solution. Once I built the project, it worked.

Comment: Just a side note, rebuild cleans and then builds the solution. So you don't need to clean before rebuild.

Comment: Worked for me if the definition is in the same js file. Still getting this if the definition is in a different file.

Answer (score 43):

Just had the same issue and it seems like there is a problem with VS 2015 and TFS. I got the problem after I merged some files to another branch.
Tried several things and it worked:

- Close all open files and then VS
- Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols->Empty Symbol Cache
- TFS Check in and get latest (For some reason it worked after this)

Not sure why it occurs but this worked for me, it might also be worth to clear TFSTemp folder as mentioned by zvi.

**EDIT**

This path: `%TMP%\TFSTemp` can be copy-pasted into windows explorer to access TFS temp

Comment: Emptying the symbol cache didn't work for me. I don't use TFS either.

Comment: Empty Symbol Cache worked for me. Thanks. You need to close all documents first.

Comment: But after I open decument, make breakpoint and debugging my code, the error occurs again. Can anyone help me further?

Comment: @toha There might be a problem to youre symbol file location/server, are you using a custom one or the Microsoft Symbol Server. Try disable/enable this

Comment: The problem occured when I try to debug the apps. (Attach to process w3wp) Then, I try to go to definition for function, or variable the error occurs. cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret. Then I need to stop the debugger, and Close All Document, and reopen the document again. Then it back to normal again. Then if I debug again, the error occurs again. So, the answer above maybe is not best answer. Need more investigation about this. Need suggestion please.

Comment: In my case, only doing "Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols->Empty Symbol Cache" worked, didn't need to close anything or do anything else, thanks.

Comment: Works like a charm !

Comment: In my case it was an issue with SVN - I had one file in conflicted state and reverting it back from the repo immediately fixed the problem.

Comment: My solution was:
1. Close all files
2. Clean solution
3. Unload all the projects
4. Close VS
5. Open VS (dont open files)
6. Reload all projects
7. Clean solution
8. Build Solution

Answer (score 20):

The following fixed this for me:

- In Solution Explorer, right click the solution name.
- Select "Clean Solution"

After this successfully completed, I no longer received the error, and I didn't have to close and reopen anything.

Comment: Same worked for me as well.

Answer (score 10):

I have the same problem after update visual studio, so this is how do I solve the problem.

1. Close visual studio.
2. Delete all .vs folder from my project.
3. Open visual studio.
4. Open my project.

Hope this helpful for anyone who has this problem.

Answer (score 9):

Clean your cache symbols (Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols > EmptySymbolCache). 
Open your solution in administrative mode.

this resolved my issue.

Comment: Just opening Visual Studio in Administrative mode (run as administrator) solved the issue for me.

Comment: And not for me.

Comment: Just opening Visual Studio in Administrative mode (run as administrator) solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 9):

Just do it:

- Close Visual Studio
- Go to project folder and delete .user file (may be hidden)
- Open Visual Studio

Comment: Thank you!! This is the one that did it for me.  Quick and painless.  In my case, this was only occurring in one project of the solution so I really didn't want to do anything to affect the whole solution or user settings in VS in general.

Answer (score 7):

Close visual studio then remove the hidden file name .vs on that project and open again the visual studio then build the project. Boom! All good!

Answer (score 6):

The answer above is correct, but the path is slightly off, try this instead:

```
%AppData%\..\Local\Temp\TFSTemp
```

Comment: this worked, but I also had to rebuild the involved projects.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the `\..\`, but I don't have a folder named `TFSTemp` anywhere on any of my computers.

Comment: The folder does not exist at my computer

Comment: I did not understand this answer. So I go to this folder, and clean up.
Please, can you change the answer?

Answer (score 6):

I've done all things above but my problem did not solve (trying to open project by VS 2017),

after that I realized that the problem was my csproj file. My project (mvc)

was created by VS 2015... So I edit my csproj file and replace

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" />
```

by this :

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.7\build\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.7\build\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" />
```

It was all about the version of DotNetCompilerPlatform.

(the way that I understood this issue was that I created new mvc project by 
VS 2017 and compared both csproj files - the new one and the one that created by VS 2015 - )

---

*Additional related info by https://stackoverflow.com/users/15667/xan (since answers are locked)*

For me (VS2019 opening an older solution) it was only affecting **one** project in the solution. The Imports looked like this:

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" />
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
```

The working projects only had the

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
```

line, so I removed the first 2 and intelisense / go to definition etc. started working again.

**HOWEVER** the web project now wouldn't run due to missing Roslyn csc compiler.

In the end the solution that worked overall was to **update the `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` and `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` Nuget packages for the project.**

Comment: Thanks, this fixed one of my older projects not being able to navigate symbols.

Comment: Expanded the answer with a similar situation which worked for me in VS2019.

Comment: For me, I had to remove the two compiler packages entirely.  The issue was caused by hand-migrating my csproj from package.config to PackageReference.

Answer (score 4):

Ran into this problem when using **F12** to try and go to a method definition.

All of the mentioned items (except the `/resetuserdata` - which I didn't try because it would be a pain to recover from) didn't work.

What did work for me:

- Exit Visual Studio
- From a Command Prompt, go to the folder for your solution and run the following code (this deletes ALL **bin** and **obj** folders in your solution):

  ```
  FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /B /AD /S bin') DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%G"
  FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /B /AD /S obj') DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%G"
  ```
- Restart Visual Studio.  Opening the solution should take a bit longer as it now rebuilds the **obj** folders.

After doing this **F12** worked!

As a side note, I normally place this in a batch file in my solution's folder, along side the `.sln` file.  This makes it easy to run later!

Comment: Removing `bin` and `obj` folders fixed the problem (rebuild solution did not work for me), so **I think this answer is more usefull** becuase `/resetuserdata` is way too much.

Comment: I got the error `%%G was unexpected at this time.` According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/9311607/740639 the double-percent is for use inside a batch file. I switched the two `%%G` to `%G` and the script worked on the command prompt. Sadly, the script did not work for me.

Comment: Manually deleting bin and obj folder also did the trick for me

Answer (score 3):

Recently upgraded to VS 2017 15.5.0 and came across this problem. I tried:

1. Deleting the symbol cache
2. Deleting my .vs folder.
3. Rebuilding solution.
4. Running devenv /resetuserdata

Sadly, none of these worked. I noticed that this was only happening on some projects and not others. On the project where it was failing, I ended up switching all of the framework versions to 4.7.1, did a clean/rebuild and my "Go to Definition" started working again.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say this is due to the new Roslyn C# compiler, in its github issue tracker you can find many of the actual developers encountering this and trying to fix it, but at present it is still open: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/9602

I've spent some time around this also, and I lost the battle. But the following workaround I've found works well for me.

**WORKAROUND**

1. Change the keyboard shortcut **F12 -> Edit.FindAllReferences** (for TextEditor).
   This will find the definition and all references and focus the root node (definition) in the Find Symbol Results.
2. Now pressing **F12, ENTER** will do the same as F12 before.

For me it seems to work even better than just GoToDefinition, because:

- After hitting F12 you can choose a reference instead of the definition by pressing UP or DOWN
- You can simply cycle between the references and definition just with these few keys (F12, ENTER, UP, DOWN), easy to remember.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using VS 2017 15.7.5 and this stopped working for certain test files. I noticed that they were all the new ones I had recently added and that in Solution Explorer there was no arrow available to expand and see the properties / methods.

I excluded and then re-included them into my project and the go to definition command worked again.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check the namespaces of the two classes.
2. If you are adding classes in the Class library - Make sure you are using the    right Project type.
   There are two class library types. Class Library(Package) and Class Library. (Select the later one as it creates .dll file) which can then be added if needed in other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you recently installed an add-in, consider uninstalling it. That's what worked for me.

Comment: I recently installed an add-in, and when I loaded solution in the middle and try to use go definition, I got this error. After wait a couple of minutes and all projects loaded, the problem gone, no uninstalling needed.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced with the same problem and "Find all references" for selected class has solved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I also came across this once. There is something wrong with TFS in VS 2015.

I followed these steps and it worked

1. Cleared TFS Cache
   This might be here:

   C:\Users\(UserName)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\(Version)\Cache

Note: path may vary based on operating system so don't blame me.

2. Emptied Symbol Cache

   **Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols > EmptySymbolCache**
3. Restarted Visual Studio (It Might ask for connecting to TFS again)

This Worked for me.:)

Answer (score 1):

Most of the paths submitted by others either don't work or are a little backwards.

Empty this folder:

```
%localappdata%\Temp\TFSTemp
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you need to have built the project at least once for caret browsing to become available.  If you're experiencing this issue on a project you haven't built yet, try building it.  That fixed it for me so I thought I'd throw it out here.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Clean solution. Restore nuget packages.

Answer (score 0):

try cleaning the solution or clean your project, this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The following worked out for me like a charm:

1. I checked the warnings that showed up when I built the Project
2. Some of them mentioned something about assembly version conflict.
   Visual studio suggested that I clicked on the warning and hit Enter.
   A popup window offered to automatically fix the issue and so I did.
3. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

This weird bug happened to me while importing a Xamarin project into VS15.
None of the solutions listed here worked for me. After a day of frustration I also ran into a problem similar to this: [Visual Studio "Find" results in "No files were found to look in. Find stopped progress."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259398/visual-studio-find-results-in-no-files-were-found-to-look-in-find-stopped-pr)

When clicking 'find all' in the search dialog, a popup informed me that other files could not be searched through.
so i figured the reason 'go to definition' didn't work was due to the same bug, as looking for definitions in the same file did work.

**the weird solution in the above link (pressing Ctrl+Scroll Lock or Ctrl+Break a few times) solved both problems for me.**

Coloring of the code (which wasn't working when the 'Go to definition' functionality was broken) also immediately returned.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a "devenv.exe /resetuserdata", my VAssistX fails, so, actually, this reminds me that **VAssistX can resolve the problem by Goto Implementation (Alt+G)**.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I (semi-accidentally) changed the property `Build action` of the problematic .cs file to `Content`. Changing it back to `Compile` did the trick, which makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

After I read that this particular issue was fixed in the roslyn compiler ([see this issue at GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/17360)), I **updated Visual Studio** from version 15.0.x to 15.3.1. It works like a charm now.

Answer (score 0):

For me the navigate works just NO XAMARIN SOLUTIONS.
That suggestions here DIDN´T WORKS. :(
Devenv.exe /resetuserdata not works for me.

My solution was:
Re-create the solutions, project, folders and works.
No import. 
Detail: my project was on the VS 2015, the error was on the VS 2017.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error for quite sometime now until I couldn't take it anymore so I have tried all possbile solutions above, but none worked for me. I noticed that the error only pops up on a certain project only (like what a user mentioned above) but not on other projects. Because of that, since nothing is working, I cloned my project again on a different folder and it started working again.

Answer (score -2):

For some reason my call_name.xaml.vb class had been excluded from the project (it seemed to happen after I got latest version from TFS). I just had to include it again and it works now!