# VS2015 doesn't show errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

When I'm working in VS2015, it seems that I don't get errors, not even upon building. I know this because I put in this following line:

```
txtDoesn'tExist.Text = "";
```

This doesn't blow up, there is no compiling errors, and theres no red squiggly indicating this is wrong, even though...it is - it doesn't exist.

Any help of how to get this working?

Comment: Is the code you show above in a file that is part of the build?
Can you show your project structure?

Comment: Its not part of the build; I threw it in there to try to trip the error-checker. And I'm not sure what you mean by showing the project structure...

Comment: And I don't know if they're related, but I'm also getting the error that was asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33029127/go-to-definition-cannot-navigate-to-the-symbol-under-the-caret).

Comment: More information would help try and get a repro. Like what kind of project you created, maybe a screen shot of the Solution Explorer, etc.

Comment: Can you provide an image of the files in solution explorer?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's obvious but have you tried restarting VS?

If that fails to work try setting the drop down on the error list tab to build only, I've heard this may help.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately neither restarting nor setting that to Build Only doesn't work.

I'm almost inclined to think that its a setting somewhere, but I can't find it for the life of me.

Answer (score 0):

Is this happening on a single project only or on all projects? Can you create a separate project and see if you get the same error.

If it is happening on a single project, try:

- Clearing all of the temp files.
- Deleting the contents of the obj and bin folders.
- Right clicking on the solution and clicking on Clean Solution.
- Right clicking on the solution and clicking on Rebuild Solution.

If it is happening on all projects, bite the bullet and remove and reinstall Visual Studio.