# Recurrent message "Cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret"

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 CE. About a week ago I started seeing a message box showing the error mentioned in the subject. It happens only if I try to open a .cs file and it's completely preventing me from working :(.
I also noticed that the projects in my solution are being "lazy loaded". That means that I open the solution and in the solution explorer I see my projects listed with a label that reads "(loading)". Once I click on them, they get loaded.

I think it could be due to a windows update, probably, because I also noticed that while working with the browser (Chrome or Edge) F12 seems to be automatically pressed because the developer tools are opened randomly. That kind of makes a consistent pattern with the issue in VS. I uninstalled the latest updates but still have the issue.

Now, I don't thing there's something wrong with my keybord, even that's possible. 
I saw many posting about this issue but couldn't find a solution yet. 
Does anybody know what could be wrong here? I'm about to completely reinstall my computer.
Thanks!

Gonzalo

Comment: Here is my solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44816302/8213536 You may try this.

Comment: Thank you! I will keep this in mind!