# CS1061: Compilation Error Message with a Repeater ItemTemplate on <%# this

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting the CS1061 error 'the aspx does not contain a definition for' on a this bit of code within a repeater: '<%# This'

Here's the ItemTemplate section within the repeater:

```
<ItemTemplate>
<tr style="height:24px;" id="row_<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CourseIDString") %>" class="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StatusClass") %>" title="<%# this.FormatStatusDesc(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StatusDesc") as string, (DateTime)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ReturnedDate"), DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CourseIDString") as String) %>">
    <td>&nbsp;<%# this.CreateNewLink(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CourseIDString") as String) %></td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

The error happens both times '<%# this' is used here:

```
<%# this.FormatStatusDesc(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StatusDesc") as string, (DateTime)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ReturnedDate"), DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CourseIDString") as String) %>">
```

and here:

```
<%# this.CreateNewLink(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CourseIDString") as String) %>
```

When I right click the .aspx file and click view code it goes into the correct place where these methods are located:

```
namespace CourseMaker
{
    public partial class CourseTemplate_2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public String FormatStatusDesc(string statusdesc, DateTime rdt, String courseID{}

        public String CreateNewLink(String childCourseID){}
}
```

The page directive:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/CourseTemplate_NoAcYear.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CourseTemplate_2.aspx.cs" Inherits="CourseMaker.CourseTemplate_2" %>
```

When I type '<%# this.' within the aspx page intellisense does show me other public methods in the code behind page like this method:

```
public void btn_new_child_onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

But when I add new methods to the code behind page these do not then show up in the intellisense list.

I have tried the following but still the compiler displays the same error:
1) Cleaned and rebuilt the solution
2) Cleared the contents of all bin folders then rebuilt
3) Deleted the files from the project and recreated them
4) Added 'optimizeCompilations="false"' to the webconfig file

This code has been working correctly in the past, something has changed I'm just not sure what. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for the error message "Cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret" which happened when I tried 'go to definition' on the this.FormatStatus line I found this article:
[Go To Definition: "Cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33029127/go-to-definition-cannot-navigate-to-the-symbol-under-the-caret)

The answer which worked for me was Closing VS, deleting the the .vs folder, opening VS and rebuilding the project and the error vanished!